# Python Multi-process share an imported Class

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I got an issue on Python multiprocessing sharing imported Class. The troubled part is like this:

**file A:**

```
class Meta:
    db_a = None
    db_b = None
    ...
# class will be initialized at the very beginning of the program and might
# be imported by all other models globally for a global variable/instance
# access, for example, a global DB access instance is in Meta
```

**file B:**

```
from file_A import Meta
def runner():
    initialize_meta_db()  # Meta's attributes now have values
    ...
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(worker, arg_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    ...

def worker(*args):
    ...
    print(Meta.db_a)  # process will print None
    ...
# a runner function which spawns 4 processes, each process will use class Meta
# to do some work.
```

But the program runs with errors that for each process, the `Meta` class is not initialized and every attribute is `None`. I know the reason why, that the `Meta` class is only initialized in the memory of the main process, and each child process will have its own raw class Meta independently.

But is there any way that I can share this class with both parent process and child processes? Thanks!

Comment: You should read the docs on [sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the initializer and initargs parameters of multiprocessing.Pool?

I modified your code slightly to do this and be able to run. It seems to do what you want.

File_A

```
class Meta:
    db_a = None
    db_b = None
    @classmethod
    def initialize_meta_db(cls, db_a='a', db_b='b'):
        Meta.db_a = db_a
        Meta.db_b = db_b
```

File_B

```
import multiprocessing

from file_A import Meta

def runner():
    Meta.initialize_meta_db()  # Meta's attributes now have values
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4, init, '')
    pool.map(worker, (1, 2, 3, 4))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def init(*initargs):
    from file_A import Meta
    Meta.initialize_meta_db()

def worker(*args):
    print('Worker {} -- Work {}'.format(args, Meta.db_a))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner()
```